# Unit Tests: create completed tasks for ActivityHistory?

Tags: unit-test, tasks

In unit tests, is there a specific way of creating completed tasks so that they appear immediately in the ActivityHistory read-only object?   (I have batch Apex that pulls data from ActivityHistory, so I'm trying to write the unit test.)

See code snippet below.  When I run the unit test, the activity history is empty.  However, when I create completed tasks manually in the UI, the ActivityHistory is populated, and then when I run the batch Apex manually, it works as expected.  I just can't get the unit test to put the data into ActivityHistory.

```
Account acct = new Account(Name = 'Apex Test');
insert acct;

Task tsk1 = new Task(WhatId = acct.Id, Subject = 'Email: apex test', ActivityDate = date.today(), Status = 'Completed');
Task tsk2 = new Task(WhatId = acct.Id, Subject = 'Call: apex test', ActivityDate = date.today(), Status = 'Completed');
Task tsk3 = new Task(WhatId = acct.Id, Subject = 'Email: apex test', ActivityDate = date.today().addYears(-2), Status = 'Completed');
Task[] tskList = new List<Task>{ tsk1, tsk2, tsk3 };
insert tskList;

Account result = [select Id, (SELECT ActivityDate, Subject FROM ActivityHistories) from Account where Id = :acct.Id];
```

Comment: You may want to read http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/how-do-i-write-test-for-a-histories-inner-query

Comment: Thanks Mike - I overlooked the mention of seeAllData in that thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

David, have you tried setting the `SeeAllData` modifier to `true` for your test class?

I tried out your code, and it appears that in order for you to validate that the ActivityHistory table was populated, you need [start your test class with this](http://pastebin.com/pYbVgXcC): `@isTest(SeeAllData = true)`

Comment: Marty, that was it.  I had read somewhere that ActivityHistory requires View All Data permission at the UI level - I wonder if that is related, even though the unit test should be running as a system user.  Thank you for testing my code.

Comment: That is really stupid you have to do SeeAllData in order to get the ActivityHistory to show from a UnitTest.  Upvoted your answer since it did the job for me.

Comment: If you have the `SeeAllData` modifer set to true doesn't that negate any actual coverage? Hardly seems like the correct solution. In addition with the new Spring 15' release you cannot have any `SeeAllData` modifiers when you have a `@testSetup` method